# Textbox is not hitting the "TextUpdated" event when the text is wrapped in double asterisks

Tags: angular

I am fairly new to Angular2 and I am having this issue with my one of my components where it does not hit the "TextUpdated" event when the text is wrapped in double asterisks.

There is no character limit and it works fine with single asterisks but not with two.

On my text input I have

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="onJobTitleSelected($event)" />

onJobTitleSelected(jt: any): void {       
    if ((typeof jt) !== "string") {
        this.model.jobTitle = jt;
        this.model.jobTitleID = jt.ID;
        this.model.jobTitleText = jt.Text;
    } else {
        this.model.jobTitleText = jt;
    }        
    this.onJobTitleUpdated.emit(this.model.jobTitleText);
}
```

Comment: I was talking about "OnJobTitleSelected" event. It should be called every time a character is entered inside the textbox.

Comment: It doesn't hit the event when I enter double asterisks.

Comment: No. It will log only when the text is wrapped in single asterisks not in double.

Comment: I am not sure without [(ngModel)] how it works. Maybe need to post more code